# How to make a controlled textfield null again after deleting all the text from it? SPFX React/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, spfx

I have a textfield(A) (Fabric UI) on a form. I have a coachMark (Fabric UI) which appears above a button if textfield(A) is blank.

The problem I encounter is that when deleting all the text from TextField(A), it is no longer considered null. The state initialises it as null.

This is the code that triggers the conditional and it's subsequent state setting:

```
    } else if(currentStep === 8 && this.props.esscrit10 === null){
      this.setState({
        isCoachmarkVisible: true,
        coachmarkText: 'Please click the Next button.'
      }, () => {
        this.props.handler(this.state);
      });
```

I've logged what the esscrit10 textfield is when I delete all the text from it and it shows blank.
I've tried replacing null with ' ' but this causes the coachmark to not appear at all.
I believe this is a simple one to resolve but my knowledge is limited with basic programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `!this.props.esscrit10` instead of `this.props.esscrit10 === null`